# Should the Flow and Visual-Workflow tags be merged

Tags: discussion

The tags [flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flow) and [visual-workflow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-workflow) are for the same functionality and reflect the different naming that Salesforce have applied to this over time.

Would it not be sensible to merge these two into 1 tag?

Comment: Yes, it seems if you want a tag synonym approved, posting about it on meta is the way to go. I voted for it first! We'll see how long it takes to get to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree. Have [proposed this as a synomym](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/visual-workflow/synonyms)

Will require the vote process before this becomes real, community power.

Comment: This always trips me up a bit. Which tag gets "removed" the way you have it set up? Which direction *should* it go? Do we want to keep `[flow]` or would we rather keep `[visual-workflow]`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough rep on the tags to actually vote at the moment.  The current product name is Flow in Salesforce so would that be the preferred tag now?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I always get confused too. I added flow as a synonym of visual-workflow, which I believe would become the master in my proposal. Which is exactly the other way around as Dave is proposing though. I figured that would be more specific and telling than just flow.